# Contour plot of $\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)+x^2-\frac{1}{3}y^3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am asked to draw the contour plot with directional vectors, without the use of a calculator.

My working:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = x + 2xy$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = y+x^2-y^2$$

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} = 1+2y$$

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} = 1-2y$$

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} = 2x$$

By setting first partial derivatives to 0, the stationary points are: $(0,0), (0,1), (\pm \sqrt{3}/2, -1/2)$

How do I determine the nature of stationary point for $(-\sqrt{3}/2, -1/2)$ given that $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}$ and its y counterpart are both 0? The rule I learnt is that they should be positive to be local max or min and negative to be saddle.

Correction: $f_{xx}f_{yy} > f^2_{xy}$ for local max or min and $f_{xx}f_{yy} < f^2_{xy}$ for saddle. But both are zero at that point. Also that $f_{xx}>0$ is a min and $<0$ is a max.

Given that the 3 points other than $(0,0)$ are saddle points, how should the contour plot be made? I am only aware that max and min should be surrounded by contour lines and saddle points are points where contour lines can cross. It would also be possible to find the equation of line near them using first order Taylor approximation but they are not helpful at all.

Corrected for notation and typos. Didn't realise I typed it wrongly.

Comment: It seems there are a few misconceptions going on: The compact notation for $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{d}{dx} f$ is $\frac{d^2 f}{dx^2}$. Also, your characterization of saddle points is incorrectly stated; the relevant quantity is the determinant of the Hessian, i.e., $f_{xx} f_{yy} - f_{xy}^2$ (for a $C^2$ function $f$, which is the case here).

Comment: Oops...made the correction. All are zero at that point, so how do we determine?

Comment: Do you mean $x^2y$ in the problem statement?